# how to search for all controls on the form in dev express (including sub reports)

Tags: controls, devexpress

I have a dev express report. I want to search for all controls on the report.

The normal convension in windows forms would be:

```
foreach (Control c in Control.ControlCollection)
{
         ........
}
```

Unfortunately this will not work in Dev Express form. Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of such questions regarding to find control in report or highlighting cell on mouse over etc..

```
xrLabel1.Text = ((XRLabel)((XtraReport)xrSubreport1.ReportSource).FindControl("xrLabel1", false)).Text;
```

[subreport control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q274105.aspx)  - **Check attached sample here**
[How can set the text of a label on a Subreport?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q272922.aspx)

Check this code snippet to take some idea for your functionality..

```
Private Sub XtraReport1_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    Dim collection As XRControlCollection = (CType(CType(sender, DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport),
Q274540.XtraReport1)).Detail.Controls
    For i As Integer = 0 To collection.Count - 1
        If TypeOf collection(i) Is XRLabel Then
            If (CType(collection(i), XRLabel)).DataBindings.Count <> 0 Then
                'your code here
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[XRControl.BeforePrint Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic)

Report have some structure and you have find control at particular container  as you do you in GridView. e.g. find control in editTemplate .. the particular container of the control

Check these links get more information about this:
[Loop thru controls of Report or find all visible strings](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ39828.aspx)
[Find TableCell Controls inside a report](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q22545.aspx)
[Find all databound controls on report](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q274540.aspx)